# how can I read history from RTC workItem jazz

Tags: rtc, jazz, ibm-jazz

how can I read history from RTC workItem.  I want to check some attribute change and its value before and after change form history. By jazz API. 
how its is possible? Please help .

Answer (score 1):

Ragarding attributes, you can see more at "[Working with Work Item Attributes](http://rsjazz.wordpress.com/2013/01/02/working-with-work-item-attributes/)"

> If you have the Attribute ID available as a string, you can use this code to get the attribute.

```
IWorkItemClient workItemClient = (IWorkItemClient) fTeamRepository.getClientLibrary(IWorkItemClient.class);
IAttribute someAttribute= workItemClient.findAttribute(fProjectArea, "some_attribute_ID", monitor);
```

For the history, this [thread can help](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/7046/how-to-get-the-history-of-an-work-item)

> you can use `IItemManager.fetchCompleteState()` to get the full item in its historical state.
>   If you want to get the full history you can also get all state handles at once using `IItemManager.fetchAllStateHandles()` instead of walking the history using `IAuditable.getPredecessorState()`.

Comment: Hi VonC,how can I get attribute itself from history of workitem ?

Comment: @VarunGupta you can check out https://jazz.net/forum/questions/87341/how-to-fetch-the-workitem-built-in-custom-attribute-id-and-value?page=1&focusedAnswerId=87383#87383

Comment: the mentioned link is not have the answer of my query. can you please help me on this?

Comment: @VarunGupta it is a start. I don't have more specific elements.

Comment: Is it possible to get history for all the files in a particular component of a Project area?
For Ex if file PropertyReader.java has been modified by Developer A most recently..
Need to get the list like PropertyReader.java Developer A

I was able to get the history in CLI using

scm show history -r $URL -u $userId -P $pwd -w $ws --component icdp_core_as /source/common/Adapters/com/bac/icdp/consumer/common/PropertyReader.java

But i need run this for each file to get the history of all the files..

Answer (score 0):

Use the below snippet:

```
IWorkItem workItem = workItemClient.findWorkItemById(id, IWorkItem.FULL_PROFILE, monitor);

IItemManager itm = teamRepository.itemManager(); 
List history = itm.fetchAllStateHandles((IAuditableHandle) workItem.getStateHandle(), monitor);
System.out.println("Record history details:-");
for(int i = history.size() -1; i >= 0; i--){
    IAuditableHandle audit = (IAuditableHandle) history.get(i);
    IWorkItem workItemPrevious = (IWorkItem) teamRepository.itemManager().fetchCompleteState(audit,null);
    //Operations to be carried on workItemPrevious
}
```